# Finding the conjugates of primitive root of unit in the field of $p-$adic complex number.

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $10^{th}-$root of unity. We know that its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $$f(z)=z^{4}-z^{3}+z^{2}-z+1,$$ and it splits over $\mathbb{C}$ as $$f(z)=(z-\zeta)(z-\zeta_{1})(z-\zeta_{2})(z-\zeta_{3}),$$ where each $\zeta_{k}$ is another primitive $10^{th}-$root of unity. And we call these $\zeta_{k}'$ the *conjuate* of $\zeta$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Now, denote $\mathbb{C}_{p}$ the completion of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{p}$ with respect to the extension of the $p-$adic absolute value, and $\mathbb{C}_{p}$ is called *the field of p-adic complex number*. Again, this minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. $f(z)$, can split over $\mathbb{C}_{p}$ because it is algebraically closed, and it will also result in four conjugates, namely, $\xi_{1},\cdots,\xi_{4}$.

My question is, is it possible to find the explicit form of these four conjugates? If not, is it possible to compute the $p-$adic norm of them? for example, what is $|\xi_{1}-1|_{p}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Aren't the conjugates going to be $\zeta^3$, $\zeta^7$, and $\zeta^9=1/\zeta$ regardless of the field (assuming $f(z)$ splits in the field)?

Comment: As @GregMartin comments... even though they're not necessarily conjugates over $\mathbb Q_p$ ... and, likewise, $\zeta-1$ satisfies a uniform quartic polynomial with coefs in $\mathbb Z$, even in cases where that poly is not irred over $\mathbb Q_p$. In particular, after some easy computations, we find that the product of the four values $\zeta^k-1$ with $k=1,3,7,9$ is $1$. Thus, these are $p$-adic units for all $p$ (perhaps lying in some extension...), since at worst they are $p$-adic integers, etc.

Comment: @GregMartin ah.. ok, and do you know how I can compute, say $|\zeta^{3}-1|_{p}$?

Comment: Just making more explicit what @paulgarrett says, these roots already lie (i.e. $f$ already factors completely) in $\mathbb Q_p$ iff $5$ divides $p-1$, e.g. $p=11$, so there's no conjugacy. In this case, Hensel's Lemma makes them as explicit as one could ever want (and they all have $p$-adic distance $1$ from $1$).

Comment: @OP: Do you know how to compute the $p$-adic norm of any element which is algebraic over $\mathbb Q_p$? If not, the best people can give you here is a number without understanding.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg if I understand it correctly, say  $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$, then $$|x|_{v}=|N_{\mathbb{Q}_{p}(x)/\mathbb{Q}_{p}}(x)|_{p}^{\frac{1}{[\mathbb{Q}_{p}(x):\mathbb{Q}]}}$$ where $v|p$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I think that you guys have made things pretty clear, and the reason for me to have this dumb confusion is my lack of knowledge of algebraic number theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, in a more-beginner-like context, which is certainly fair-enough for Math Stack Exchange! (Maybe even one of the best reasons to have this site! :)

So, yes, in principle, there is no mystery here, in the sense that long-known, relatively elementary (by some standard) methods answer the question. Which is *not* to say that everyone on the street (or in the hallways in math depts) could instantly explain it.

So: the primitive 10th roots of unity are zeros of $\Phi_{10}(x)$, the 10th cyclotomic polynomial, which is (provably) $(x^{10}-1)/\Phi_1(x)\Phi_2(x)\Phi_5(x)=x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$. Then $\zeta-1$ for any of the zeros satisfies $x^4-...+(1-1+1-1+1)$, and the constant term is $\pm 1$. That is, while all of the $\zeta^\ell-1$ are certainly algebraic integers, their product is $1$, so they are all (global!) *units*. So they are units $p$-adically for all $p$, whether or not they are in $\mathbb Q_p$ or some finite extension.

Comment: Great Answer! Thank you!!